# Error in opening a report from a form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I've designed a simple form and a few reports in Access. I have designed it in Windows 7, with Access 2010, and when I open it on a Windows XP PC with Access runtime, I get the error "The expression on click you entered as the event property setting produced the following error". 
Can anyone help me with this one, please?

```
Private Sub cmdShoppingList_Click()
  On Error GoTo Err_cmdShoppingList_Click
    Dim stDocName As String

    stDocName = "Shopping List"
    DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acViewReport
  Exit_cmdShoppingList_Click:
    Exit Sub

  Err_cmdShoppingList_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_cmdShoppingList_Click

End Sub
```

I hope to get the answer soon.  Here is a pic of my error message:

[image]

Comment: I suspect you cannot open the report from the database window either, is this true? If so, post the sql for the report.

Comment: This has nothing to do with vb.net right?

Comment: FYI: you don't have to take a picture of your computer screen to screenshot an error message. Try Alt + Print Screen instead - you can then paste the image in any program, such as MS Paint and save.

Comment: I'm with Remou, can we see what the recordset is for your report as the code sample above looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since it works in Windows 7, but not in Windows XP, it sounds to me like you may have put an ActiveX control on the report that is only present in Windows 7.  When distributing MS Access databases/projects you will need to distribute whatever DLLs/OCXs you've used to the target computer.